# Ошибка A component is changing an uncontrolled input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

Использую React + TypeScript + Mobx. Сделал форму с инпутом, все работает но браузер в консоле выдает ошибку. Что я делаю не так?

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to
>   be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to
>   controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Вот код формы:

```
@observer
  export class SearchForm extends React.Component {

    @observable
    private _inputText: string;

    submitForm = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
          <InputField
            value={this._inputText}
            onChange={action((value: string) => this._inputText = value)}
          />
       </form>
    );}}
```

Input:

```
interface Props {
  value: string;
  onChange: (inputText: string) => void;
}

@observer
export class InputField extends React.Component<Props> {

  onChange = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  this.props.onChange(event.currentTarget.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.props.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private _inputText: string = ""
```

вот и ответ